# PHP Curl, Login via Post then Post to another form after redirect?

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

I was following the curl examples here to log into a wordpress site via curl:
- http://www.sitepoint.com/using-curl-for-remote-requests/

Here is what I need to do:

1. Log in wordpress
2. Redirect to form page
3. Post to form page

From the examples in the url I posted above, the curl does a post to login but I am unsure how to make it post again after it redirects to the form after logging in.

All from a script hosted somewhere else.

Comment: Better get to work then :D

Comment: you are not new to this site... that's not even a question

Comment: Is it even possible to do that?

Comment: Making it "post again" is trivial - just do what you do to make it post, again. The only thing you need to read up on is how to send the cookies in the second request, to prove that you've logged in. The [`curl_setopt` manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) lists `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` options which I believe are what you need for that.